# Mapping a List wrapped in a generic struct

Tags: c#, automapper

## Context

I'm building an application to view and modify configuration settings for a custom web crawler. The configuration includes which sites to crawl. The sites can be organised into collections. Certain settings can be specified either on the collection level or on the site level. For example, a collection has a `TimeOut` setting, and a site within the collection can either use the collection's `TimeOut`, or specify its own value. In order to facilitate this, I defined a struct similar to `Nullable<T>` called `Inheritable<T>` which is basically this:

```
public struct Inheritable<T> {
    public bool IsInherited { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

So an Inheritable property either has its `IsInherited` flag set to true, or it has its own value. Note that this has nothing to do with inheritance in an object orientation context.

The settings also include a list of pattern to search for:

```
public class Pattern {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
}


public class SiteSettings {
    public Inheritable<int> TimeOut { get; set; }
    public List<Pattern> Patterns { get; set; }
    // Many more properties
}
```

I'm using AutoMapper to convert DTO objects to viewmodel objects.

The following code does exactly this. It includes the full implementation for Inheritable and can be copy/pasted into LinqPad (you need to reference the AutoMapper dll for it to run.)

### Self-contained example:

```
public class SiteSettingsDto {
    public Inheritable<int> TimeOut { get; set; }
    public List<PatternDto> Patterns { get; set; }
}

public class SiteSettingsViewmodel {
    public Inheritable<int> TimeOut { get; set; }
    public List<PatternViewmodel> Patterns { get; set; }
}

public class PatternDto {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
}

public class PatternViewmodel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Expression {get; set; }
}

void Main() {
    var siteSettingsDto = new SiteSettingsDto() {
        TimeOut = 5,
        Patterns = new List<PatternDto>() {
            new PatternDto() {
                Name = "Google",
                Expression = "google"
            },
            new PatternDto() {
                Name = "Wikipedia",
                Expression = "wikipedia"
            }
        }
    };

    Mapper.CreateMap<PatternDto, PatternViewmodel>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<SiteSettingsDto, SiteSettingsViewmodel>();

    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    var siteSettingsViewmodel = Mapper.Map<SiteSettingsViewmodel>(siteSettingsDto);
    siteSettingsViewmodel.Dump();
}

public struct Inheritable<T> {
    private readonly T valueField;
    private readonly bool isInheritedField;

    public T Value {
        get { return valueField; }
    }

    public bool IsInherited {
        get { return isInheritedField; }
    }

    public Inheritable(T value) {
        valueField = value;
        isInheritedField = false;
    }

    public Inheritable(bool isInherited) {
        valueField = default(T);
        isInheritedField = isInherited;
    }

    public Inheritable(bool isInherited, T value)
    {
        valueField = value;
        isInheritedField = isInherited;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return IsInherited ? "Inherited" : valueField == null ? "": valueField.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator Inheritable<T>(T value) {
        return new Inheritable<T>(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Inheritable<T> value) {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

## The actual issue

I want to make the `Patterns` property to also be Inheritable. When I make the `Patterns` property Inheritable, AutoMapper needs extra guidance to map from `Inheritable<List<PatternDto>>` to `Inheritable<List<PatternViewmodel>>`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it.

This is what my `SiteSetting` objects look like now:

```
public class SiteSettingsDto {
    public Inheritable<int> TimeOut { get; set; }
    public Inheritable<List<PatternDto>> Patterns { get; set; }
}

public class SiteSettingsViewmodel {
    public Inheritable<int> TimeOut { get; set; }
    public Inheritable<List<PatternViewmodel>> Patterns { get; set; }
}
```

This is the exception thrown by `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`:

> The following property on UserQuery+Inheritable`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UserQuery+PatternViewmodel, query_mtnney, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] cannot be mapped:
>
> Patterns
>
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type UserQuery+Inheritable`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UserQuery+PatternViewmodel, query_mtnney, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].
>
> Context:
>
> Mapping to property Patterns from UserQuery+Inheritable`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UserQuery+PatternDto, query_mtnney, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to UserQuery+Inheritable`1[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UserQuery+PatternViewmodel, query_mtnney, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>     Mapping from type UserQuery+SiteSettingsDto to UserQuery+SiteSettingsViewmodel
>
> Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.

## Update

I have been able to get the mapping I want using the following type converter, however I still get the above exception when I call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`, which is unfortunate, and I'd still like to solve it.

```
public class InheritablePatternConverter : ITypeConverter<Inheritable<List<PatternDto>>, Inheritable<List<PatternViewmodel>>> {
    public Inheritable<List<PatternViewmodel>> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var source = (Inheritable<List<PatternDto>>) context.SourceValue;
        return new Inheritable<List<PatternViewmodel>>(source.IsInherited, Mapper.Map<List<PatternDto>, List<PatternViewmodel>>(source.Value));
    }
}
```

Use via:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Inheritable<List<PatternDto>>, Inheritable<List<PatternViewmodel>>>().ConvertUsing(new InheritablePatternConverter());
```